# Convert a string of numbers to get a value from a multidimensional array

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a string, such as `010` to get the value from that incremented index. The array could look something like the following:

```
$data[0] = [
    '0 Depth'
];
$data[0][1] = [
    '01 Depth'
];
$data[0][1][0] = [
    '010 Depth'
];
```

The function will need to essentially grab the string inside `$data[0][1][0]`. I've taken a look at `array_reduce`, but I don't think it's what I'm looking for.

What's the most fundamental way to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: use a reference loop, i.e split the sting, loop over then set the value of the item to the current nested item

Comment: ignore the `.` in the linked dupe, is the same solution, just use nothing as separator

Comment: could also use eval ;p https://3v4l.org/aQfsp

Comment: Thanks guys! `eval` should be fine to use for this one!